# VSCode - Differentiate abstract class and implementations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a way in VSCode (maybe an extension) to know if a class I'm writting is an abstract class or an implementation. It would also be really cool if I could see the abstract methods that I need to implement to finish the implementation.

```cpp
class MyAbstractClass {  // Abstract
  virtual void myFunc() = 0;
}

class MySubAbstractClass : public MyAbstractClass {  // Still abstract
  virtual void someOtherFunc();
}

class MyImplementation : public MyAbstractClass {  // Maybe a different highlight color for the implementation ? Or a hover popup ?
  void myFunc() override;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if VS Code actually does that, but some IDE Editors render abstract class names in italics, or provide them in that manner in a class hirararchy tree shown as sidebar. I am also not sure if the Whole Tomato Visual Studio extension, is capable of such feature, but I believe chances are good. Also dunno, if that extension is available for VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

You can view all the methods of a class if you press and hold `Ctrl` and hover over the parent class.[image: Viewing the class methods]

Comment: Looks awesome! Do you have any extension for that? On my setup it only triggers `Definition Preview Hover` which just show the definition of the class.

Comment: I use the following [C/C++ Extension made by Microsoft.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)

Comment: Same though  could it be a version thing ?

Comment: If you can't get it to work. You can hold `Ctrl` and click on the parent class. It will take you to the file where it is implemented and you can see all the methods of the class there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, though @Khalil 's answer looks really cool, I was unable to reproduce. If anyone comes around looking for the same thing, a workaround is to try to instanciate the class, VSCode will list all pure virtual methods that need to be inherited...

[image: VSCode screenshot]